# Permutations from 1 to 10, starting always with 1 and with a step not bigger than 6

Tags: permutations

I would appreciate your help on the following:

I need all permutations from 1 to 10, starting always with 1 and with a step not bigger than 6.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The number of permutations is not too large. You can just write them down one by one, systematically, and then count. Maybe while doing so you will see a pattern that will let you get the answer a little faster.

Comment: I have developed an algorithm in MATLAB and found 103320 permutations. I would like to find, if possible a generic function when the max number increases but the constraints remain the same.